# Loop em R com indexação e matriz

Tags: r, loop, matriz

Estamos tentando utilizar o comando `for` para rodar uma função y (digamos `y=5+3x+4z`) variando os valores de z (digamos que z é uma combinação de 5 valores `z=c(1,2,3,4,5)`) e que x é uma distribuição normal de tamanho 1000. Após imprimir os valores, que usamos por meio de indexação, como poderíamos transformar esses resultados em uma matriz de 1000 linhas e 5 colunas (1000 observações para cada valor de z)?
Depois de usar o comando `for`:

```
z=c(1,2,3,4,5)
for(i in c(1,2,3,4,5)) print(y<-5+3x+4z[i]))
```

Tentamos definir uma matriz de y que não funciona pois ele imprimi a primeira coluna nas outras 4 restantes.

Comment: poste o código que você está usando, e o resultado esperado para podermos ajudar.

Comment: z=c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<-5+3x+4z
for(i in c(1,2,3,4,5)) print(matrix(5+3x+4z[i],100,5))

Comment: x=c(1,2,3,4,5)
z=c(1,2,3,4,5)
for(i in 1:5) print(matrix(5+3x+4z[i],100,5))
o resultado esperado tem que ser uma matriz de cinco colunas (cada coluna para os 5 z's) e 5 linhas (cada linha para os 5 x's).

Answer (score 2):

Difícil entender qual o resultado esperado pelo OP, mas aqui vai uma tentativa.

```
Y = matrix(NA,nrow=0,ncol=5)
x=c(0,1,2,3,4) 
z=c(1,2,3,4,5) 
for (i in 1:5) {
  y = 1*x+2*z[i]
  Y = rbind(Y,y) 
}  
Y
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
y    2    3    4    5    6
y    4    5    6    7    8
y    6    7    8    9   10
y    8    9   10   11   12
y   10   11   12   13   14
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo uma distribuição normal de média 0 e desvio padrão 1:

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Y <- matrix(NA, 1000, 0)

for (i in z) {
  y <- 5 + 3*x + 4*i
  Y <- cbind(Y,y)
}

print(tail(Y))

                y         y        y        y        y
[995,]   4.450844  8.450844 12.45084 16.45084 20.45084
[996,]   9.072672 13.072672 17.07267 21.07267 25.07267
[997,]   8.609610 12.609610 16.60961 20.60961 24.60961
[998,]   6.977799 10.977799 14.97780 18.97780 22.97780
[999,]   5.896328  9.896328 13.89633 17.89633 21.89633
[1000,] 13.005769 17.005769 21.00577 25.00577 29.00577
```

Ao final, Y terá 1000 linhas e 5 colunas. Ou seja, 1000 observações para cada valor de z.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa usar `for` neste caso.

Segue uma solução com `sapply`:

```
y <- function(x,z) 5+3*x+4*z
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
z <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
resultados<-sapply(z, y, x=x)
```

Os resultados serão 5 colunas (uma para cada z) com 1000 observações:

```
head(resultados) ### mostrando apenas os 6 primeiros
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,]  7.120639 11.12064 15.12064 19.12064 23.12064
[2,]  9.550930 13.55093 17.55093 21.55093 25.55093
[3,]  6.493114 10.49311 14.49311 18.49311 22.49311
[4,] 13.785842 17.78584 21.78584 25.78584 29.78584
[5,]  9.988523 13.98852 17.98852 21.98852 25.98852
[6,]  6.538595 10.53859 14.53859 18.53859 22.53859
```